# iText7 keep table rows together

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext7

I need to keep 2 (particular) table rows together and never split these between pages. Of course the `SetKeepTogether` does not work, because I don't have common "container" to turn this on on. Is my custom `TableRenderer` my only option?

Comment: You can have a parent table with one column occupying 100% of the width and `setKeepTogether` for cells containing two rows of your main table that you want to keep together. This is not exactly `keepWithNext` functionality that you are looking for, but pretty close.